# Check which file is changed after receiving event when using WaitForMultipleObjects in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, notifications, filesystems

I need to  monitor a directory in the filesystem, and notify when a file was renamed. I've seen in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/obtaining-directory-change-notifications) that I can use `FindFirstChangeNotification` for registering to a specific filesystem event, and `WaitForMultipleObjects` for waiting that the event occurs.

So I register to the file rename event in a specific directory (recursively)

```
std::vector<HANDLE> dwChangeHandles;
auto h = FindFirstChangeNotification(m_rootPath.string().c_str(), true, FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME);
if (h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
  dwChangeHandles.push_back(h);
}
```

and then I wait in a infinite loop the event that occurs:

```
while (m_threadRunning) {
  dwWaitStatus = WaitForMultipleObjects(dwChangeHandles.size(), dwChangeHandles.data(), FALSE, INFINITE);
  switch (dwWaitStatus) {
    case WAIT_OBJECT_0: {
      if (FindNextChangeNotification(dwChangeHandles.at(0)) == FALSE)
      {
        printf("\n ERROR: FindNextChangeNotification function failed.\n");
        ExitProcess(GetLastError());
      }
    } break;
  }
}
```

The problem is that I have the notification, but I can't find a way to check which file is changed. I'd like to know the old filename and the new one. Is there a way to know which file was renamed?

Comment: not need use `FindFirstChangeNotification` at all. need use `ReadDirectoryChangesW`

Comment: `FindFirstChangeNotification` only tells you that something has changed, but not what changed. You need to enumerate the contents of the directory and save a snapshot, and then on each change take a new snapshot, compare with the previous one, and figure out the difference. `ReadDirectoryChangesW` may report details of individual changes - unless too many changes happen at once, overflowing its internal buffer, and then you have to fall back to scanning the directory and comparing snapshots anyway.